# Data retrieving on the same jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

How can I retrieve data in a text field from a SQL table on a jsp page on the basis of the data entered by a user in a particular text field  on the same jsp page using a servlet and HTML . so that I can use the retrieve d data of text field to update another table.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can try this 
...

```
<% 
  String ITEM = "";
  ResultSet lRstDet  = null;   

  String SQL  = "SELECT * FROM TB_TEST;
  DB_TEST.makeConnection();      
  DB_TEST.executeQuery(SQL);
  lRstDet = DB_TEST.getResultSet();

  if(lRstDet.next())
  {
    ITEM= lRstDet.getString("ITEM");
  }
  DB_TEST.takeDown();
%> 

--- html part ---
<input type="text" name="ITEM" value="<%=ITEM%>">
```